# Reading contents of a file when its being handled by some loader already

Tags: webpack, webpack-loader, raw-loader

rawloader is used to read a file in webpack. Lets say we want to read the contents of a file thats already being handled by another loader. Can we use the rawloader (or any other technique) to do that?

Lets say .myext has a loader that returns an object. but at the same time i want to read contents of that file. Is there an easy way?

```
import resource from '/path/res.myext'
```

Comment: explain what you are trying to do in real scenario, maybe there is a better solution for that

Comment: Trying to render the source of res.myext (within <code> tags) in one of my compoments. Need the raw data for that.

Comment: yeah but how does that help in this use case?